# How does the QML ListView estimates the height/width of it's contentItem

Tags: algorithm, qt, listview, qml

I am wondering how the `ListView` estimates the height/width of it's `contentItem`, though the delegate is a `Component` that you can't ask, and the size might vary from one delegate-instance to another.

- It does not use the average size of the current instances.
  Otherwise in *Example 1*, if one element is pressed, the estimated size would be **3055.5** if all instances are counted, or **3125** if only those in the view are counted. It estimates **2845**
- It does not use the maximums size of all current instances.
  If one element is pressed, the estimated size would be **7500**. If the maximum height is only considered for non-instantiated elements, it would be **6350**
- It does not use the minimum size of all current instances.
  The estimation would be definitely to small.

And even if you know the right size, you can't help it, for in *Example 1* we know the correct `contentHeight` would be **2500** if nothing is pressed, and **2650** if something is pressed. In *Example 2* the right `contentHeight` would be **1225** but setting manually setting the value is of no use, as it is overwritten soon after.

*Example 1:*

```
ListView {
    id: lv1
    width: 200
    height: 500
    model: 50
    onContentHeightChanged: console.log('estimated contentHeight', contentHeight)
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 200
        height: ma.pressed ? 150 : 50
        border.color: 'black'
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: index
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: ma
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

*Example 2:*

```
ListView {
    id: lv1
    width: 200
    height: 500
    model: 50
    onContentHeightChanged: console.log('estimated contentHeight', contentHeight)
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 200
        height: index
        border.color: 'black'
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: index + ' ' + ((index * (index + 1)) / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know. Let's look through the source code. :)

Looking at the code, [here's](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitemview.cpp) where the `contentWidth` and `contentHeight` are set:

```
void QQuickItemViewPrivate::updateViewport()
{
    Q_Q(QQuickItemView);
    qreal extra = headerSize() + footerSize();
    qreal contentSize = isValid() || !visibleItems.isEmpty() ? (endPosition() - startPosition()) : 0.0;
    if (layoutOrientation() == Qt::Vertical)
        q->setContentHeight(contentSize + extra);
    else
        q->setContentWidth(contentSize + extra);
}
```

The `startPosition()` and `endPosition()` functions are declared [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitemview.cpp#n1596):

```
qreal QQuickItemViewPrivate::startPosition() const
{
    return isContentFlowReversed() ? -lastPosition() : originPosition();
}

qreal QQuickItemViewPrivate::endPosition() const
{
    return isContentFlowReversed() ? -originPosition() : lastPosition();
}
```

`QQuickListView`'s implementations of `originPosition()` and `lastPosition()` are both [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquicklistview.cpp#n423):

```
qreal QQuickListViewPrivate::originPosition() const
{
    qreal pos = 0;
    if (!visibleItems.isEmpty()) {
        pos = (*visibleItems.constBegin())->position();
        if (visibleIndex > 0)
            pos -= visibleIndex * (averageSize + spacing);
    }
    return pos;
}

qreal QQuickListViewPrivate::lastPosition() const
{
    qreal pos = 0;
    if (!visibleItems.isEmpty()) {
        int invisibleCount = INT_MIN;
        int delayRemovedCount = 0;
        for (int i = visibleItems.count()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if (visibleItems.at(i)->index != -1) {
                // Find the invisible count after the last visible item with known index
                invisibleCount = model->count() - (visibleItems.at(i)->index + 1 + delayRemovedCount);
                break;
            } else if (visibleItems.at(i)->attached->delayRemove()) {
                ++delayRemovedCount;
            }
        }
        if (invisibleCount == INT_MIN) {
            // All visible items are in delayRemove state
            invisibleCount = model->count();
        }
        pos = (*(--visibleItems.constEnd()))->endPosition();
        if (invisibleCount > 0)
            pos += invisibleCount * (averageSize + spacing);
    } else if (model && model->count()) {
        pos = (model->count() * averageSize + (model->count()-1) * spacing);
    }
    return pos;
}
```

`averageSize` seems to be calculated [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquicklistview.cpp#n1286):

```
void QQuickListViewPrivate::updateAverage()
{
    if (!visibleItems.count())
        return;
    qreal sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < visibleItems.count(); ++i)
        sum += visibleItems.at(i)->size();
    averageSize = qRound(sum / visibleItems.count());
}
```

That function is called by [`QQuickListViewPrivate::visibleItemsChanged()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquicklistview.cpp#n767), which is called by [`QQuickItemViewPrivate::refill()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitemview.cpp#n1796), which is called... all over the place. Basically whenever *anything* related to the view or its items changes.

`visibleItems.at(i)->size()` is [pretty much equivalent](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitemview_p_p.h#n77) to `QQuickItem::width()`/`QQuickItem::height()`:

```
inline qreal itemWidth() const { return item ? item->width() : 0; }
inline qreal itemHeight() const { return item ? item->height() : 0; }
```

From what I can see, it more or less takes the height of every item that is visible (could probably be equated with "currently instantiated") in the view, adds them together and then divides that sum by the number of visible items. You can confirm this by adding the following debug output:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/src/quick/items/qquicklistview.cpp b/src/quick/items/qquicklistview.cpp
index 0351077..acfb88a 100644
--- a/src/quick/items/qquicklistview.cpp
+++ b/src/quick/items/qquicklistview.cpp
@@ -1296,6 +1296,7 @@ void QQuickListViewPrivate::updateAverage()
     for (FxViewItem *item : qAsConst(visibleItems))
         sum += item->size();
     averageSize = qRound(sum / visibleItems.count());
+    qDebug() << "sum" << sum << "visibleItems.count()" << visibleItems.count();
 }

 qreal QQuickListViewPrivate::headerSize() const
```

The output of this before clicking an item:

```
qml: estimated contentHeight 5000
sum 550 visibleItems.count() 11
qml: estimated contentHeight 2500
sum 850 visibleItems.count() 17
```

After pressing on the first item:

```
sum 850 visibleItems.count() 15
qml: estimated contentHeight 2845
```

So I would say that

> It does not use the average size of the current instances.

is incorrect to some degree. If you really want to know what the difference is, you'll need to look further into the code.

Comment: Thank you so far. That is a lot to read and understand, and I will need some time for it. Then I will accept it.

Comment: No worries. I realise that it might not be a complete answer, but hopefully it gives you a nudge in the right direction.