# Qml - Scrollable View of Pages

Tags: qt, listview, model, qml

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<parameters version="2.0">
    <page currentPage = "1">
    </page>
    <page currentPage = "2">
    </page>
</parameters>
```

Here is my qml code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 500
    minimumHeight: 500

    XmlListModel {
        id: pageXmlModel
        source: "qrc:/Config/Esempio.xml"
        query: "/parameters/page"
        XmlRole { name: "currentPage"; query: "@currentPage/number()" }
    }

    ListView {
        id: pageListView
        model: pageXmlModel
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
        clip: true
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: myPageContainer
            anchors.fill: parent
            Page {
                id: myPage
                anchors.fill: parent
                Text { text: currentPage }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can't understand why the result is only one page with the overlapped labels, insted of more pages, each one with its label.
Can someone tell me where is the mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: In your delegate you should not use `anchors.fill: parent`, as this woud - well - fill the parent.

Comment: To help you, I'd like to have [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In your case this means, you should either provide the `Config/Esempio.xml` or replace the `XmlListmodel` by a dummy `ListModel` with some dummy data.

Comment: Maybe you also want to look at the [`SwipeView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html).The interesting part is the part with the `Repeater` and `Loader`. I am unsure however if it is better than the `ListView`, performancewise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I can see in your code is in your delegate:

```
delegate: Rectangle {
    id: myPageContainer
    anchors.fill: parent    // <--- Here is a BIG problem
    Page {
        id: myPage
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text { text: currentPage }
    }
}
```

You set the delegate to fill the parent. What will happen here?

Well, the `ListView` extends the `Flickable`, so it has a `contentItem` that holds all the instances of your delegates next to each other. The size of that `contentItem` is determined by the size of all visible instances of your delegate in relation to the count of your model. How exactly it is calculated is still unknown to me. ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780845/how-does-the-qml-listview-estimates-the-height-width-of-its-contentitem) )

However, with your `anchors.fill: parent` you resize the delegate to always fill the `contentItem`. This will lead to a growth of the `contentItem`, which will lead to a growth of the `delegate` and so on. You have a binding loop.

Intrestingly, when you use the `XmlListModel` instead of a number as model, QML seems to detect this problem, and does not accept the `anchors.fill: parent`. Therefore in your example, the `widht` of each `delegate` is **0**. This leads to your problem, that you have the texts of both pages on top of each other.

**Lessons learned:** *never use `anchors.fill: parent` in the root node of a delegate.*

```
delegate: Rectangle {
    id: myPageContainer
    width: root.width
    height: root.height
    Page {
        id: myPage
        anchors.fill: parent
        Text { text: index }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(width, height)
}
```

Comment: It seems there is a bug, that the behavior of `anchors.fill: parent` is different whether you use a `QAbstractModel`-descentdent or a number. Nevertheless, it should never work.